# implementing __sync_swap() in gcc

Tags: gcc, clang, atomic, swap, built-in

GCC is lacking Clang's builtin [`__sync_swap()`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#sync-swap). I have some code that requires it, and I'm trying to figure out the way to mimic this in GCC. The Clang docs allude to this not being as simple as a single `__sync_*` or `__atomic_*` operation.

How could `__sync_swap()` be mimmiced in GCC?

Comment: Looks the same as gcc's `__atomic_exchange_n` to me.

Comment: I think you're right. The clang docs must be out of date. I'm pretty sure that instruction came around before gcc had `__atomic_*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It so appears that `__sync_swap` is simply an old fashioned name for what can be achieved with more "up to date" built-ins. Lets consider a case in point (atomic macros as implemented by freebsd: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/freebsd/sys/sys/stdatomic.h):

```
#if defined(__CLANG_ATOMICS)
....
#define atomic_exchange_explicit(object, desired, order) \
    __c11_atomic_exchange(object, desired, order)
....
#elif defined(__GNUC_ATOMICS)
....
#define atomic_exchange_explicit(object, desired, order) \
    __atomic_exchange_n(&(object)->__val, desired, order)
....
#else
....
#if __has_builtin(__sync_swap)
/* Clang provides a full-barrier atomic exchange - use it if available. */
#define atomic_exchange_explicit(object, desired, order) \
    ((void)(order), __sync_swap(&(object)->__val, desired))
....
```

It's fairly clear from the example that freebsd devs consider the newer clang's `__c11_atomic_exchange`, gcc's `__atomic_exchange_n` and older `__sync_swap` (it at all available) to have identical semantics. The later is only used as last resort option, in case newer built-ins are not available.